# Laravel: how to get nested models

Tags: php, laravel, nested, models

Could not you to direct me in right way.

I have four models: `"Item"` belongs to several `"Category"` belongs to `"Shop"` belongs to "City"

How can i select Item with all nested models (for json response, for example, it is not important).

In other words, i want to get sctructure like that:

```
 item
  category_1
    shop_1
    shop_2
      city_1
  category_2
```

I able to get categories by `$item->with('categories')` statement, but how i can get nested items in `category` (`shops`, and then - `cities`).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)**

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax.

So to achieve that, just do this:

```
$item->with('categories', 'categories.shop', 'categories.shop.city');
```

Comment: How i have to name methods in models?

Comment: Please, share your `models` in you question.

Comment: i am asking about, how should i name method in Category model - categoriesShopCity?

Comment: No. Each model must have its own relationship. As you said, `Category` has many `Shop` and `Shop` belongs to a `City`.

Comment: Thx. I solved my question. You showed me right way :)

Comment: great. any time.